# Html и CSS - убрать выделение у иконок-ссылок, но оставить текст-ссылкам

Tags: html, css, классы, background, link

Я новичок в Web-вёрстке, сейчас активно изучаю помимо Python, созрел один вопрос, который прошу помочь решить, я сделал выделение для текст-ссылок: навигация в шапке сайта:

```
<a href="#step">Этапы работы</a>
```

И для этого прописал в CSS подобную структуру:

```
a {
    color: black;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    padding-top: 5px; 
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
    text-decoration: none;
  }

a:hover {
    background: rgba(69.50, 35.62, 72.45, 0.60); 
    color: black; 
  }
```

но благодаря такому коду, стали выделяться иконки-ссылки: Viber, Gmail и т.п. - при наведении на них курсором.
Хотелось бы узнать, как оставить подобное выделение у текстовых ссылок, но убрать эти рамочки фона для иконок?

Comment: Когда вы прописали стиль так, то вы для всех тегов <а> задали единый стиль

Comment: Да, я это понял, просто не подумал про иконки...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ограничить селектором по родителю:

```
.header a:hover {
  background: rgba(69.50, 35.62, 72.45, 0.60); 
  color: black; 
}

<div class="header">
  <a href="#step">Этапы работы</a>
</div>
```

Можно ограничить классом:

```
a.link:hover {
  background: rgba(69.50, 35.62, 72.45, 0.60); 
  color: black; 
}

<a class="link" href="#step">Этапы работы</a>
```

Comment: Ну и по id еще можно добавить

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сам подумал: "неужели класс создавать", показалось, что это будет глупо... =)